# Vuejs and google maps: Cannot create new object of Polyline class

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, I want the user to be able to draw a freehand polygon on click of a button. I have it implemented in plain JS and now want to use it in vue (using vue-cli).

I am using this plugin for vue: https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/blob/vue2/API.md
Here is the code I am using:

```js
var self = this;
// calls another method which disables map controls
self.disableMap();
// below line is fine
console.log(self.$refs.map.$mapObject);
// event handler is being called
self.$refs.map.$mapObject.addListener('mousedown', function() {
  // the below line results in undefined
  console.log(self.$refs.$polylineObject);
  let poly = new(self.$refs.map.$polylineObject)({
    map: self.$refs.map,
    clickable: false
  });
})
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have `console.log(self.$refs.$polylineObject);` did you mean `console.log(self.$refs.map.$mapObject);`?

Comment: No. I want to create an object of PolyLine class which is supposed to be available. But it's not.

Comment: Ah, sorry I have a typo in *my* comment too. I should have asked "did you mean  `console.log(self.$refs.map.$polylineObject);`"? (Note the `.map` property missing in your `console.log`)